# Conditional statement for Repeater Controll in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am populating some data in a table with 6 columns using a repeater control in ASP.NET (VB) using the enclosed code.

I want a piece of code to achieve the following functionality by attaching an if/elseif/else condition to the repeater controll:

1. For the record with<%#Eval("SOLID")%> = "40103" then the data to be displayed in one cell, merging all 6 columns in to one (ideally using colspan = 6).
2. For the record having <%#Eval("SOLID")%> = "40105" then the data to be displayed in two cell, merging the second and third column.
3. For all the other records the data to be displayed in the actual format.

I have gone through various sites for a solution, but in vain. Please help me

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server">           
    <headertemplate>
        <tr style="height:25px;vertical-align:middle">
            <th class ="dg_rpt_center" align="left" width = "10%" >
                <asp:Label ID="Label7"  runat="server" class ="lbl105" >SOLID</asp:Label></th>
            <th class ="dg_rpt_center" align="left" width = "30%">
                <asp:Label ID="Label10"  runat="server" class ="lbl105" >SOL Name</asp:Label></th>
            <th class ="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width = "10%">
                <asp:Label ID="Label11"  runat="server" class ="lbl105" >Target</asp:Label></th>
            <th class ="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width = "10%">
                <asp:Label ID="Label12"  runat="server" class ="lbl105" >Achievement</asp:Label></th>      
            <th class ="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width = "10%">
                <asp:Label ID="Label13"  runat="server" class ="lbl105" >Margin</asp:Label></th>
            <th class ="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width = "10%" >
                <asp:Label ID="Label14"  runat="server" class ="lbl105" >Growth</asp:Label></th>
        </tr>
    </headertemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width = "10%"><asp:LinkButton ID="lblsolid"  runat="server" class ="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("SOLID")%>' OnClick='subDtClick' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SLNO")%>'></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td align="left" width = "30%"><asp:Label ID="lblsolname"  runat="server" class ="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("NAME")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td align="right" width = "10%"><asp:Label ID="lbltgt"  runat="server" class ="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("TGT")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td align="right" width = "10%"><asp:Label ID="lblach"  runat="server" class ="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("ACH")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td align="right" width = "10%"><asp:Label ID="lblmrgn"  runat="server" class ="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("MGR")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td align="right" width = "10%"><asp:Label ID="lblgr"  runat="server" class ="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("GRW")%>'></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the repeater [ItemDataBound event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) at all?

Comment: Yes. But merging table cells need to be done in design level. Right?

Comment: Not when there is certain business logic involved (i.e. `if(SOLID == 40103) { //display change }`). Yes you are affecting the presentation/design layer, but you probably want that logic in your code behind file (to add or remove a class from the table row).

Comment: I amean using itemdatabound for changing font, enable/disable control and to make a entire row invisible. But I  do not know how to merge table cells in the itemdatabound event

Comment: Well you can access the row in your itemdatabound event. Something like this: `<tr runat="server" id="row">` in the `<ItemTemplate>` and in the itemboundevent `var row = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("row");`. You can do the same thing with the table cells and add `colspan` attributes and remove them if you need to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the info, which is new to me.  I checked the code in theitemdatabound event, but could not find out how I could set colspan attribute for a row

Comment: Well, this is where it gets tricky for you. You would need to give `ID`'s and `runat="server"` to all your `<td />`'s and set your `colspan` accordingly and remove any excess `<td>`'s. `<table>`'s have a very strict structure and yours has to maintain a 6 column setup. You can't merge cells with css unfortunately. I can give a example snippet if you are curious about what I am talking about.

Comment: An example snippet is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f0350223d2626a1011f) makes sense. The front-end Repeater is on top and the ItemDataBound event is below.

Comment: Thanks for your apt snippet.  I got the idea.  According to the code, I have created ID for table cells in the following manner:

Comment: <td align="left" width = "10%" id = "tdSOLID"><asp:LinkButton ...
<td align="left" width = "30%" id = "tdNAME"><asp:Label .... 
<td align="right" width = "10%" id = "tdTGT"><asp:Label ....

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion with the all the table row talk... I was hoping to just add a class to the row and have a css style to merge the nested cells accordingly, but I could not come up with anything

Comment: You will also need `runat="server"` on the table cells if you wish to access them from the code behind

Comment: But getting error in the line -
Dim tdSOLID = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tdSOLID"), TableCell)
Error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'

Comment: Sorry the code was untested. the casts should be `(HtmlTableCell)` and not `(TableCell)` in the snippet

Comment: I put the runat="server" against all td tags. But still I am getting the above error

Comment: I changed it.  But now it is showing error against the line - tdSOLID.Text = mergedCellValues

Comment: Did you change the code to this?: `Dim tdSOLID = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("tdSOLID"), HtmlTableCell)`

Comment: Update it to this: `tdSOLID.InnerText = mergedCellValues;` Sorry I gave you the wrong cast in my snippet

Comment: If this works let me know and I will post it as an answer for others

Comment: What a beauty.  I could achieve the desired result.  I could not believe it.  Thank you sir for your support, apt snippet and real time response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can write your logic in the `ItemDataBound` event of the Repeater control. You will need to get references of your table cells and labels, then set your `colspan`, merge your label values, and hide any extra cells.

ASPX page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater3_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr style="height: 25px; vertical-align: middle">
                    <th class="dg_rpt_center" align="left" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" class="lbl105">SOLID</asp:Label></th>
                    <th class="dg_rpt_center" align="left" width="30%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" class="lbl105">SOL Name</asp:Label></th>
                    <th class="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" class="lbl105">Target</asp:Label></th>
                    <th class="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" class="lbl105">Achievement</asp:Label></th>
                    <th class="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" class="lbl105">Margin</asp:Label></th>
                    <th class="dg_rpt_center" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" class="lbl105">Growth</asp:Label></th>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td id="tdSOLID" runat="server" align="left" width="10%">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblsolid" runat="server" class="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("SOLID")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SLNO")%>'></asp:LinkButton></td>
                    <td id="tdNAME" runat="server" align="left" width="30%">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblsolname" runat="server" class="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("NAME")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td id="tdTGT" runat="server" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltgt" runat="server" class="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("TGT")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td id="tdACH" runat="server" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblach" runat="server" class="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("ACH")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td id="tdMGR" runat="server" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblmrgn" runat="server" class="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("MGR")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td id="tdGRW" runat="server" align="right" width="10%">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblgr" runat="server" class="lbl9N" Text='<%#Eval("GRW")%>'></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
public void Repeater3_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

            var lblsolid = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lblsolid");

            if (lblsolid.CommandArgument == "40103" || lblsolid.CommandArgument == "40105") {

                //Labels
                var lblsolname = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblsolname");
                var lbltgt = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("lbltgt");
                var lblach = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblach");
                var lblmrgn = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblmrgn");
                var lblgr = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblgr");

                //Table Cells
                var tdSOLID = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdSOLID");
                var tdNAME = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdNAME");
                var tdTGT = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdTGT");
                var tdACH = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdACH");
                var tdMGR = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdMGR");
                var tdGRW = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdGRW");

                if (lblsolid.CommandArgument == "40103") {
                    //merge all label values into a single string
                    var mergedCellValues = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", lblsolname.Text, lbltgt.Text, lblach.Text, lblmrgn.Text, lblgr.Text);

                    //set the text value of the first table cell and span it 6 columns
                    tdSOLID.InnerText = mergedCellValues;
                    tdSOLID.Attributes.Add("colspan", "6");

                    //remove extra cells
                    tdNAME.Visible = false;
                    tdTGT.Visible = false;
                    tdACH.Visible = false;
                    tdMGR.Visible = false;
                    tdGRW.Visible = false;
                } else if (lblsolid.CommandArgument == "40105") {
                    //same concept as above, but with different colspan and cell hiding
                }

            }

        }
    }
```